# What does those + and - means when a background subshell finished?

Tags: linux, bash

For example

```
for x in 1 3 5 6 4 2 8 ; do sleep $x & done ; wait
[1] 3338
[2] 3339
[3] 3340
[4] 3341
[5] 3342
[6] 3343
[7] 3344
[1]   Done                    sleep $x
[2]   Done                    sleep $x
[6]-  Done                    sleep $x
[3]   Done                    sleep $x
[5]-  Done                    sleep $x
[4]-  Done                    sleep $x
[7]+  Done                    sleep $x
```

What the meanings of the plus and minus signs above?

Comment: Look at `JOB CONTROL` section in `man bash`

Comment: You won't see them in scripts, only interactive shells, so arguably this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Basically you are right, but IMHO we should be not too pedantic about that!

Comment: @hek2mgl, I would have filed a close vote over the issue myself if I were feeling too pedantic today. :)

Answer (score 1):

Current job is flagged with a **+** and the previous job is flagged with a **-**

Looking at what you have displayed. Sleep 1, 2, and 3 have finished. Sleeps 4, 5, and 6 are still "running" in the background. `sleep 7` was the last task sent to the background.

Answer (score 1):

from [man](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/jobs.html) jobs you get:

*current*:

> The character "+" identifies the job that would be used as a
>   default for the fg or bg utilities; this job can also be specified
>   using the job_id %+ or %%. The character "-" identifies the job that
>   would become the default if the current default job were to exit; this
>   job can also be specified using the job_id %-. For other jobs, this
>   field is a space character. At most one job can be identified with "+"
>   and at most one job can be identified with "-". If there is any
>   suspended job, then the current job will be a suspended job. If there
>   are at least two suspended jobs, then the previous job will also be a
>   suspended job.